# How to relocate tenants?

Tags: dream-house-days

I'm trying to remember how to relocate one of my tenants into a new apartment in Dream House Days. Help? I know it's next to the evict button but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

First you tap on the apartment that your tenant is currently in, then you click the "Request Move" icon, then it will give you the choice of permanently removing them or to change their apartment for 5 green cash in game, then it gives you an option to choose to which empty apartment to move them to.